# Gallery won't scroll properly when image in custom list item is loaded

Tags: java, android, lazy-loading

Here's the situation:

I have a custom list item containing an ImageView, and some TextViews.  I am lazy loading images to the ImageViews.  When I use this in a ListView, it works fine.

I also want to use it in a Gallery.  There are three scenarios:

1. **lazy load images, not touching the spacing:** The items overlap, but
   scroll fine
2. **don't load images, Gallery.setSpacing(0):** The items are spaced
   correctly, the scrolling works, but I have no images.
3. **lazy load images, Gallery.setSpacing(0):** The items are spaced
   correctly, scrolling doesn't work, just behaves really jittery and
   snaps back to original position.  If I scroll very fast, repeatedly, it will start moving,         but very poorly

Because it all works perfectly in a ListView, I can't understand what's going wrong.  I know it's nothing wrong with my image loader, and I know it's nothing wrong with my layout.  It seems like Gallery is having trouble handling changes to the list item.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention, there's a placeholder image loaded in the ImageView before the images are loaded, and the ImageView has a fixed size.

Does anybody have any idea what I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think that because yo are lazy loading the images, when onMeasure is called on each item in the gallery, it doesn't know how big the image going to be (as it isn't loaded yet), and so it can't set the spacing to 0.

Maybe you should set your default gallery item size, or update the size of the view as the image is loaded?

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention it in my question, but I have a placeholder image loaded in the ImageView, and the ImageView has a fixed size in dip.